# mysql not gaving desired result

Tags: mysql

i am executing this query.

```
select (select FollowersCount from webanalysis.DataTwUser_followers_history where DataTwUserID='80943' and Date <='2015-01-12' order by Date desc limit 1) - (select FollowersCount from webanalysis.DataTwUser_followers_history where DataTwUserID='80943' and Date >='2014-12-12' order by Date  limit 1) as new;
```

and it is giving me '18446744073709551606' this as answer, but i want '-9' as answer.

if i execute this **query 1**,

```
select FollowersCount from webanalysis.DataTwUser_followers_history where DataTwUserID='80943' and Date <='2015-01-12' order by Date desc limit 1;
```

it will give me '193' as answer. and if execute this **query 2**

```
select FollowersCount from webanalysis.DataTwUser_followers_history where DataTwUserID='80943' and Date >='2014-12-12' order by Date  limit 1;
```

it will give me '202' as answer, so i want to do this,

193 - 202 = -9.

where i am wrong? need help.

Comment: The issue is subtraction of UNSIGNED integer values, MySQL thinks the result should be an UNSIGNED integer. The subtraction operation overflows the lower bound of unsigned integer (zero), and MySQL wraps the result around to the largest value. (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got unsigned integer values, you're doing a subtraction, and MySQL is bounding the result to unsigned integer...  the value overflows (underflows) the lower limit, and "wraps".

To fix this, CAST or CONVERT the unsigned values to signed, before the the subtraction.

```
SELECT CAST(( val1 ) AS SIGNED) - CAST(( val2 ) AS SIGNED) AS foo
```

(substitute `val1` and `val2` with your subqueries that return the unsigned integer values)

If you prefer, you can use the CONVERT function in place of CAST

```
SELECT CONVERT(( val1 ),SIGNED) - CONVERT(( val2 ),SIGNED) AS foo
```

Comment: The behavior you observe is documented here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html).  The CAST and CONVERT functions are documented here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html).

Comment: yep !!!! this work.. when i use CAST function it give me error that ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION CAST does not exist. but CONVERT work for me. and one more thing why CAST function give me error?

Comment: @archish: the most likely reason for that error is a *space* between the function name and the following paren. E.g. **`SELECT CAST (a...`** will throw the error. The behavior you observe is documented here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/function-resolution.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/function-resolution.html).  (My bad, I see the typo in my answer, there's a space after the second `CAST`, that shouldn't be there... I would have caught that if I had actually tested that.)